# Constructors with variable number of arguments

Tags: java, object-oriented, constructor

Assume that we have a class with multiple constructors which may look like the following:

```
public class C 
{
      private String id;
      private int a;
      private int b;
      private int c;

     C(String id, int a){}
     C(String id, int a, int b){}
     C(String id, int a, int b, int c){}
     C(C[] cs){}

     // This method will be used to print objects created by C(String id, int a)
     public void printC1() {}

     // This method will be used to print objects created by C(String id, int a, int b)
     public void printC2() {}

     // This method will be used to print objects created by C(String id, int a, int b, int c)
     public void printC3() {}
}
```

The methods `printC1`, `printC2`, `printC3` have a lot of similarities. Could anyone support me with some hints how I should redefine the class `C` in order to follow design principles like DRY, ...

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. The example code that you have posted is not reviewable in this form because it leaves us guessing at your intentions.  Unlike Stack Overflow, Code Review needs to look at concrete code in a real context. Please see [Why is hypothetical example code off-topic for CR?](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1709)

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't provide code, we review code you've written. Depending on your problem, another site of the [StackExchange network](//stackexchange.com/) can help you. Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Noting the above comments about reviewing code - not providing it - I offer the following hint: research "method overloading" for java. Or if the print method depends on how the constructor is invokes, set a private flag and then use a series of conditionals in the single `print` method. Try to encapsulate and hide as many decisions as possible from your user. This is not an answer because your question does not fit within the spirit of CodeReview.

Answer (score 2):

Use `vararg`s in your constructor. Have one print method that prints any of `a`, `b`, `c` that exist. Also, why are you printing from a method on C? That's probably a bad design.

```
public final class C {

    private String id;
    private int[] values;

    public C(final String id, final int... values) {
        this.id = id;

        if ((values == null) || (values.length > 3)) { /* do something */ }
        this.values = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    }

    public void print() {
        for (final int value : values) { /* do something */ }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write one part of code in `printC1` and then just call it from `printC2`. Add one line to print additional information In C2 and from C3 just call `printC2`.